# Two image not create thumbnail at same time in Php

Tags: php, image

i am trying to upload two images ("image" and "coverimage") at same time with thumbnail but second code/"image"
not creating thumbnail and not uploading to folder,First Code/"coverimage" working properly but "image" not creating thumbnail
Where i am wrong ? Here is my code

```
//uploading image ( working fine and creating thumbnail)
if( isset( $_FILES['CoverImage'] ) ){
            if (file_exists($_FILES['CoverImage']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['CoverImage']['tmp_name'])) 
                {
                    $filenames = time() . uniqid(rand()) . $_FILES['CoverImage']['name'];
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["CoverImage"]["tmp_name"], "ShopCoverImage/" . $filenames);
                    $source_paths = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ShopCoverImage/' . $filenames;
                    $target_paths = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ShopCoverImage/thumb/';
                    $config_manips = array(
                        'image_library' => 'gd2',
                        'source_image' => $source_paths,
                        'new_image' => $target_paths,
                        'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
                        'create_thumb' => TRUE,
                        'thumb_marker' => '',
                        'width' => 100,
                        'height' => 100
                    );
                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manips);
                    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                        $error= $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                        return $error;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $saveArr['CoverImage'] = $filenames;
                    }
                    $this->image_lib->clear();
            } 
        }       

        //image uploading ( not creating thumbnail)
if( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ){
if (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) 
                {
                    $filename = time();
                    $filename = time() . uniqid(rand()) . $_FILES['image']['name'];
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "Profile/" . $filename);
                    $source_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Profile/' . $filename;
                    $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Profile/thumb/';
                    $config_manip = array(
                        'image_library' => 'gd2',
                        'source_image' => $source_path,
                        'new_image' => $target_path,
                        'maintain_ratio' => FALSE,
                        'create_thumb' => TRUE,
                        'thumb_marker' => '',
                        'width' => 100,
                        'height' => 100
                    );
                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
                    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                         $error= $this->image_lib->display_errors();
                        return $error;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //$saveArr['image'] = $filename;
                    }
                    $this->image_lib->clear();
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code :

Remove from second upload image code

```
 $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
```

and replace with below code

```
$this->image_lib->initialize($config_manip);
```

Comment: showing following error after replace your code

"Unable to load the requested class: Image_library"